# Cookiecutter - Django: Anymail[SES] boto3 region error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, cookiecutter, django-anymail

I am trying to deploy to AWS(EC2) a Cookiecutter Django project.
The AWS user with this credentials has ful S3, SES and SNS policies.
The EC2 server has also a role with full SES/S3 policies.

In production file in envs I have the keys set up like this.

```
DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxx
DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxx
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=xxxxxxxxxx
```

In settings I have

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env("DJANGO_AWS_S3_REGION_NAME", default=None)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env("DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.amazon_ses.EmailBackend"
ANYMAIL = {}
```

All nice and fine until the project tries to send an email using SES and it crashes with the error bellow .

Until now I have tried:

- adding DJANGO_AWS_S3_REGION_NAME to the production file in envs - no result
- adding the region in aws config using aws cli - no result
- overriding the settings in ANYMAIL ={} with credetials and region - no result
- making a blank project, just adding the aws credentials and not changing anything else - no result
- creating manually on another project a boto3.session.client with the same credentials and sending a mail - it works

This is the error. The second part with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_raw_email' repeats a lot after this.

```
django_1    | [2021-08-13 13:58:14 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Error handling request /accounts/signup/
django_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django_1    |     response = get_response(request)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
django_1    |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
django_1    |     return func(*args, **kwds)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
django_1    |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
django_1    |     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
django_1    |     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 230, in dispatch
django_1    |     return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 74, in dispatch
django_1    |     response = super(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, self).dispatch(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 204, in dispatch
django_1    |     return super(CloseableSignupMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
django_1    |     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 102, in post
django_1    |     response = self.form_valid(form)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py", line 248, in form_valid
django_1    |     return complete_signup(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 209, in complete_signup
django_1    |     return perform_login(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 175, in perform_login
django_1    |     send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup, email=email)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py", line 346, in send_email_confirmation
django_1    |     email_address.send_confirmation(request, signup=signup)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py", line 62, in send_confirmation
django_1    |     confirmation.send(request, signup=signup)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py", line 169, in send
django_1    |     get_adapter(request).send_confirmation_mail(request, self, signup)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 464, in send_confirmation_mail
django_1    |     self.send_mail(email_template, emailconfirmation.email_address.email, ctx)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py", line 136, in send_mail
django_1    |     msg.send()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
django_1    |     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anymail/backends/base.py", line 89, in send_messages
django_1    |     created_session = self.open()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anymail/backends/amazon_ses.py", line 44, in open
django_1    |     self.client = boto3.session.Session(**self.session_params).client("ses", **self.client_params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 258, in client
django_1    |     return self._session.create_client(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 847, in create_client
django_1    |     client = client_creator.create_client(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 86, in create_client
django_1    |     client_args = self._get_client_args(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 355, in _get_client_args
django_1    |     return args_creator.get_client_args(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 71, in get_client_args
django_1    |     final_args = self.compute_client_args(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 148, in compute_client_args
django_1    |     endpoint_config = self._compute_endpoint_config(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 220, in _compute_endpoint_config
django_1    |     return self._resolve_endpoint(**resolve_endpoint_kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 302, in _resolve_endpoint
django_1    |     return endpoint_bridge.resolve(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 430, in resolve
django_1    |     resolved = self.endpoint_resolver.construct_endpoint(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 133, in construct_endpoint
django_1    |     result = self._endpoint_for_partition(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 148, in _endpoint_for_partition
django_1    |     raise NoRegionError()
django_1    | botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
django_1    |
django_1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
django_1    |
django_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
django_1    |     response = get_response(request)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 114, in __call__
django_1    |     response = response or self.get_response(request)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
django_1    |     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 104, in response_for_exception
django_1    |     log_response(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 224, in log_response
django_1    |     getattr(logger, level)(
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1475, in error
django_1    |     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
django_1    |     self.handle(record)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
django_1    |     self.callHandlers(record)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
django_1    |     hdlr.handle(record)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 952, in handle
django_1    |     self.emit(record)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 122, in emit
django_1    |     self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 125, in send_mail
django_1    |     mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 104, in mail_admins
django_1    |     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
django_1    |     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anymail/backends/base.py", line 94, in send_messages
django_1    |     sent = self._send(message)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anymail/backends/base.py", line 124, in _send
django_1    |     response = self.post_to_esp(payload, message)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anymail/backends/amazon_ses.py", line 67, in post_to_esp
django_1    |     response = payload.call_send_api(self.client)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anymail/backends/amazon_ses.py", line 127, in call_send_api
django_1    |     return ses_client.send_raw_email(**self.params)
django_1    | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_raw_email'
```

I'll appreciate any input. I'm out of ideas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've probably figured out, the problem is boto3 doesn't know what AWS region you're trying to operate in:

> `botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.`

The region name comes from boto3 configuration. From [Anymail's SES docs](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/esps/amazon_ses/#installation):

> you must make sure boto3 is configured with AWS credentials having the necessary IAM permissions. There are several ways to do this; see [Credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials) in the Boto docs for options. Usually, an IAM role for EC2 instances, standard Boto environment variables, or a shared AWS credentials file will be appropriate. For more complex cases, use Anymail’s [`AMAZON_SES_CLIENT_PARAMS`](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/esps/amazon_ses/#std-setting-ANYMAIL_AMAZON_SES_CLIENT_PARAMS) setting to customize the Boto session.

It seems like you might be try to mix some of the "several ways" to provide boto3 credentials, which could be causing confusion.

Note that your `AWS_*` Django settings don't come into play. boto3 doesn't know about Django settings. [Anymail's SES settings docs](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/esps/amazon_ses/#settings) describe which Django settings Anymail will pass along to boto3. (And `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME` wouldn't be relevant anyway, because S3 is not the same service as SES. I'm guessing those `AWS_*` Django settings may be for some other app, maybe django-storages.)

If you want to provide AWS credentials specifically for Anymail in settings.py, you can do that with Anymail's [`AMAZON_SES_CLIENT_PARAMS`](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/esps/amazon_ses/#std-setting-ANYMAIL_AMAZON_SES_CLIENT_PARAMS) setting. E.g.:

```py
# (Be sure to add DJANGO_AWS_REGION_NAME to your env to use this example)
ANYMAIL = {
    "AMAZON_SES_CLIENT_PARAMS": {
        "aws_access_key_id": env("DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
        "aws_secret_access_key": env("DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
        "region_name": env("DJANGO_AWS_REGION_NAME"),
    },
}
```

Comment: Hey medmunds, I tried this before on my project and did not worked. But I tried again today on the blank project and it worked! So this is the way, I think I can figure it out for the project. Thanks a lot!